# Programming pic16F1459 through PICKIT3

Tags: c, embedded

I have this weird problem when i do a USB programming for a pic16F through PICKIT3, everything works as expected. As in, the communication with PC and the PIC, protocols, everything looks perfect. But the major problem is, the device gets detected in windows only if pickit 3 is also connected to the device. Even though the the PIC board is connected to the PC through USB and that is how the communication happens, the entire scenario is like, everything happens only if PICKIT 3 is also connected to the PIC Development board. Can someone help me in picking up the actual fault ?

Comment: Does your embedded code respond to interrogation by the host PC opsys? http://www.eeherald.com/section/design-guide/esmod14.html

Comment: Yeah, literally everything works... Apart from the fact that i need a pickit to keep it alive.

Comment: The PICKit manual says the host establishes a link with the PICKit and the blue LED shows the communication link is active. So does the embedded code mimic whatever the PICKit does to establish a connection, when the host enumerates its USB ports?

Comment: The embedded code is a separate entity. I just wrote the USB Stack for the Development board which in turn works only if the ICSPCLK/PGC pin of the PICKIT is connected to the development board..

Comment: If it is only PGC that must be connected to enable otherwise standalone operation of your board doesn’t it imply your program relies on the state of PGC? Or electrically as a pullup? Or even as a phantom voltage source or return?